# How to trigger maven snapshot build after maven release build

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

After performing a Maven release build using the release-plugin, I would like to automatically start a maven build to create the new snapshot artifacts.

We are not using Jenkins pipelines, just a single Jenkins job to build the master branch.

The release build is performed with the Jenkins release-plugin, which creates two commits to the master branch.  The first commit to sets the version to the release version, and then a build is performed and the release artifacts are pushed to the repository.  The second commit sets the version to the next snapshot build, but no build is performed.   So the repository contains the release artifacts, but not the new snapshot artifacts.   Until the new snapshot artifacts pushed to the repository, tools/developers will not be able to access the new snapshots artifacts.  So I would like to trigger jenkins to build the new snapshot artifacts after a release build.

How do I configure jenkins do that?

Comment: Just curious: What is the idea behind this?

Comment: Where have you configured the release build? What kind of CI/CD tools you are using? Usually by the release build there will be automatically triggering the snapshot after the release being done...

Comment: @khmarbaise Why should there be an automatic snapshot build after a release build?

Comment: Depends on how you have configured your pipelines...often you have configured to build main/master by each change... which means a changes is being produces by the release... (depends also of course if you build your release on main/master or on a different branch)...

Comment: @khmarbaise  I have updated my question wth more details.    Thanks for any help you can provide.